# Feed shows incorrect reputation change

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, ios-app

Viewing the feed on the iOS app, I'm seeing an incorrect reputation change under "Earlier Today."

[image: Incorrect Rep Change]

The feed shows +10 rep on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38461452/2415822) (which was correct at the time), and -2 on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38444544/2415822), which does not currently have any up or downvotes, but the question is currently at -2.

Is this a bug?  Did someone downvote my answer and remove the downvote in the grace period?  Or is the app incorrectly reporting the -2 of the question as a rep loss for me here?

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is functioning by design.  The answer did in fact receive a down vote that was then removed.  The feed on the iOS app doesn't ever re-poll old feed items for updates so that -2 just represents the specific moment in time when the item was generated.  Hopefully there's another feed item that gives you +2 on that answer.

Comment: Thanks Brain.  I didn't see a +2 in the feed, which is why I posted the bug report.  Is the only reason you were able to verify that because you are a SE employee?  I didn't see anything about the downvote in the answer's timeline.

Comment: @JAL Yeah, there's a moderator tool to see the timeline of all events for a post.  Not sure why the +2 didn't show up in the feed.  There could be a timing bug.