# Incorrect error message for answer not found

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, deleted-answers, 404-not-found

I recently posted an answer to a question on Aviation.SE but was pointed out to be wrong (I miss read the question, amateur mistake!) so I deleted my answer.

On the iOS app the notification for a comment left on my answer still appears in my feed, which when clicked displays "Question not found"

The question is still there, just my answer was deleted, surely this should say "Answer not found".

Also why is the link to the comment still in my feed?

[image: Screenshot]

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPhone 5s (Global)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Comment: The feed doesn't retroactively update so notifications do stay in the feed even if they are deleted (see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284630/307988)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed (in a way) in 1.6.4.

Now instead of saying "Question not found" we say "page not found", which isn't really better in a sense that it does more, but it's better in the sense that it doesn't say the question itself is gone.

There's not much the app can do about bringing you to the question or telling you that the answer itself was deleted and not the question, because that information isn't exposed by the inbox.  It just gives us the comment ID and we figure the rest out.

As for why it's still in your feed, that's just the way the feed acts, always adding new data but not clearing out invalidated stuff.  It's possible that at some point we'll rework things but it's not a priority.