# Edits not reflected in "feed" in IOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Cellular)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

When a question title that was poorly worded is fixed, anything in the feed that had happened before shows the previous title.  I can see that occasionally, that may be appropriate, but I suspect that most of the time it would be better to show the improved version.

Comment: I don't know how app feed works on iOS app, but on Android, it's a "one-time-update-then-forget", this also explains the "unanswered" status even though the question is answered already.

Comment: This is basically by design. Items in the feed aren't updated (see e.g. [Feed shows incorrect reputation change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281451/307988))

Comment: So they are stored somewhere instead of generated from the DB?  That seems wasteful.